# How do I programmatically find and delete a container image built through Google Cloud Build with the googleapis Artifacts API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

My goal is to find and delete a Docker container image that I previously built through Google Cloud Build (via the Node googleapis library, using the Artifacts API). I have the information passed back to me when I built the container, and I'd like to delete it via the Node googleapis library.

The image path returned by Cloud Build looks like this: "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/project-1234/dev/foo:bar"

I've tried unsuccessfully to delete the artifact as follows:

```
const artifacts = artifactregistry({ version: 'v1beta2', auth: authClient});
await artifacts.projects.locations.repositories.packages.delete({name: config.containerLocation})
```

This results in an error: *The requested URL /v1beta2/us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/project-1234/dev/foo:bar was not found on this server.* It looks like I am not designating the location properly, but it's not clear how to resolve that.

How should I delete the image?

Comment: The URL is wrong. However, you have not posted enough code and you masked too many variables to know the problem. The API endpoint starts with https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2

Comment: I'm not hitting the endpoint directly; I'm using the googleapis Node library just as shown. My code is not masked; except that the config.container has a different project, container and tag name. Other than those variables, CloudBuild provides an image location in that format exactly; and it should be possible to delete that image with the Artifacts API somehow or another.

Comment: @Aadmaa what's the value of `config.containerLocation`? Also, I suggest using a more updated library for Artifact Registry as Ricco demonstrated on his answer. Cloud Client libraries are the modern standard for accessing Cloud APIs programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Donnald. That value is the image location value returned by Cloud Build. Here, it is the string: "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/project-1234/dev/foo:bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to delete a package using Artifact Registry Cloud Client Library as this is now the recommended way to access the APIs since it is much easier to use and well documented. See [Cloud Client Library docs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#cloud-client-libraries).

The code below shows how to delete a package in Artifact Registry, given that you already know what package to delete. This is defined in `namePackage` variable and be passed to `callDeletePackage()` which will call [deletePackage()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/artifact-registry/latest/artifact-registry/v1beta2.artifactregistryclient#_google_cloud_artifact_registry_v1beta2_ArtifactRegistryClient_deletePackage_member_1_) to proceed with the delete.

```
const {ArtifactRegistryClient} = require('@google-cloud/artifact-registry');
        const client = new ArtifactRegistryClient();
async function main() {

        const projectId = 'project-id';
        const location = 'us-central1';
        const repositoryName = 'your-repository-name';
        const packageName = 'your-package-name';
        var namePackage = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/repositories/${repositoryName}/packages/${packageName}`;
      
        callDeletePackage(namePackage);

}
async function callDeletePackage(name) {
        const deletePack = await client.deletePackage({name: name});
        console.log(deletePack);
}
main();
```

---

If ever you need to programmatically get your repositories and packages you can check this code. It has `listsRepositories()`, `listsPackages()` and `callDeletePackage()`.

- `listsRepositories()` lists the available repositories, you can choose which repository has the package to delete.
- `listsPackages()` to list the packages of the selected repository
- `callDeletePackage()` to delete the package.

Code below just gets the 1st element in the returned list for both repository and package and delete afterwards. Its up to you on how to get your desired package to delete.

```
const {ArtifactRegistryClient} = require('@google-cloud/artifact-registry');
        const client = new ArtifactRegistryClient();
async function main() {

        const projectId = 'your-project-id';
        const location = 'us-central1';
        var parentRepo = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`;

        names = await listsRepositories(parentRepo);
        var nameRepo = names[0];
        console.log(nameRepo);
        var repos = await listsPackages(nameRepo);
        console.log(repos[0])
        callDeletePackage(repos[0]);
}
async function listsRepositories(parent) {
        var nameArr = []
        const repositories = await client.listRepositories({parent : parent});
        const repo = repositories[0];
        for (const data in repo) {
                nameArr.push(repo[data].name);
        }
        return nameArr;
}

async function listsPackages(parent) {
        var namePackArr = []
        const packages = await client.listPackages({parent : parent});
        const pack = packages[0];
        for (const data in pack) {
                namePackArr.push(pack[data].name);
        }
        return namePackArr;
}

async function callDeletePackage(name) {
        const deletePack = await client.deletePackage({name: name});
        console.log(deletePack);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricco. For anyone following this later: 
(1) Make sure the service account running the code has the needed Artifact role(s)
(2) If you need to authenticate through the API and you also switch from googleapis as recommended, you may also have to get GoogleAuth from 'google-auth-library' instead of from 'googleapis'